# use aliases in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, alias

I use aliases in my code, it works the first time and shows the current time, but the second time, when I call it shows past time(time showed before instead of current time)

```
  GNU nano 6.2                            aliases.sh                                     
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias TODAY="date"
echo "This shell represent differences between static substitution and dynamic substitut>
echo "==============================================================================="

DATE=`date`

echo "Static substitution"
echo "Start of bash script is: $DATE"
echo "Now I'm going to sleep for one minute"
sleep 5s

echo " end of the script: $DATE"

echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Dynamic Substitution"

DDATE=`TODAY`
echo " Current Date is $DDATE"
echo "Now I'm going to sleep for one minute"
sleep 30s
echo "end of script date is $DDATE"`
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the date to a variable so it's only being called once and then that variable is a static reference.

You could do:

```
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Dynamic Substitution"

echo " Current Date is $(today)"
echo "Now I'm going to sleep for one minute"
sleep 30s
echo "end of script date is $(today)"
```

Note that `$(...)` command substitution is generally preferred over backticks.

Comment: Thanks, its works.

Comment: maybe it's better to use $(date) instead of $(TODAY), I thought if put a command in an alias and use it as the variable it runs every time, but I was wrong.

Comment: @M.Alkhamis Yes if your alias is simply doing `date` it would be better to call date directly.  If you are doing something more complicated it may be better to use a function instead of an alias.

Comment: Welcome to the community. If the answer helps you resolve the issue, please do accept it. That will prevent it from popping up as "Unanswered" somewhere down the line. I'd recommend checking the Help, at least the sections on questions and answers, to figure out how things work. SE communities aren't similar to internet discussion forums :-)

Comment: @M.Alkhamis, also note that this has nothing to do with using an alias, just that the shell evaluates command substitutions immediately. Pretty much like function calls in the more usual programming languages, but unlike variables in e.g. Make.